# Configure linux hosts file to resolve domain name to kubernetes cluster

Tags: dns, kubernetes

So I have a simple node app for "hello node" and I am running it on a kubernetes cluster, I have exposed it as a service, configured an ingress for it and now I would like to target that service with a domain name, so I can use that instead of the ip address.

Does anybody know how to configure this? I have tried searching for External domain names and dns, but they keep pointing me back to how to configure some part of kubernetes which configures the external dns, which is not what I am looking for.

I am perhaps not using the correct terminology for this.  Can anybody help?

Comment: You mean to access it while developing? Or having an actual bought domain name that points to your application?

Comment: I could have a domain name, then I set its A record to the ip address, or I could have a hosts file, where I set the hostname/ip address and do it that way, I think from a technical standpoint its not much different, you configure the domain name externally and host the website on kubernetes